# Need to get the output as positive and negative numbers from one column into different columns from a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need a solution for the scenario below:

```
TABLE A:
col1
1
-1
6
-5
2
4
-2
5
```

I want the OUTPUT as:

```
POSITIVE     NEGATIVE
1            -1
2            -2
4            NULL
5            -5
6            NULL
```

Comment: Your results seem to presume an ordering of the rows.  Tables in SQL Server (and all databases) represent *unordered* sets.  You need a separate column to specify the ordering.

Comment: Will there always be at most one `+ve` value for the equivalent `-ve` value, and vice versa? If not, how should that be handled?

Comment: What decides the appearances of NULL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT t1.col1 AS POSITIVE, t2.col1 AS NEGATIVE
FROM (
   SELECT col1
   from tableA
   WHERE col1 > 0 ) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT col1
   FROM tableA
   WHERE col1 < 0 ) t2 ON t1.col1 = ABS(t2.col1)
ORDER BY ABS(COALESCE(t1.col1, t2.col1))
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8343/1)

Comment: 0 is normally considered positive, but otherwise I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

This correlated subquery does what you want using [`ABS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

```
SELECT POSITIVE = a1.col1,
       NEGATIVE = (SELECT TOP 1 a2.col1
                   FROM TableA a2
                   WHERE a2.col1 < 0 
                   AND   ABS(a2.col1) = a1.col1)
FROM TableA a1
WHERE a1.col1 >= 0 
ORDER BY a1.Col1
```

<kbd>[**Sql-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0952a/9/0)</kbd>

I find it easier to read as a `FULL OUTER` self `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.Col1 as POSITIVE,
       B.Col1 as NEGATIVE
FROM A
FULL JOIN A as B on (-A.col1=B.Col1)
WHERE A.Col1>0 or B.Col1 < 0
ORDER BY ISNULL(A.Col1,-B.Col1)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4781a/4)</kbd>

If POSITIVE values always exist for each NEGATIVE in the table then use LEFT JOIN instead of FULL:

```
select A.Col1 as POSITIVE,
       B.Col1 as NEGATIVE
FROM A
LEFT JOIN A as B on (-A.col1=B.Col1)
WHERE A.Col1>0 
ORDER BY A.Col1
```